# Need to contour an object using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am playing with image analysis for a project using OpenCV 3.1.0 and Python 2.7 in a virtual environment. I have to be able to detect my object as a region of interest. So far I was able to determine the contours of the object. However, as you may see below the results is far from what I need.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhQuE.jpg)

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmeR1.jpg)

My code right now:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils

im = cv2.imread('testimg.jpg')
ratio = im.shape[0] / 500.0
orig = im.copy()
im = imutils.resize(im, height = 500)
cv2.imwrite('testimgsmall.jpg', im)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('edges.jpg', im)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: A completely unscientific method would be to remark that your object is the only red thing in your image... Of course, that only applies to this particular image. @David Brenes

Comment: I have thought about implementing some sort of clustering method for my contours but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Without any information on what it is you're trying to find in an image, you're not gonna go far, no matter the method. What do you want to find exactly? Red objects? Square-shaped objects? Foreground elements in the center of the image?

Comment: I would like it for the object to vary, that's why I wanted to do it based on edges. Typically they are going to be square objects, with bright colors (different from the background). However, like in this image, the object might have labels that might be of different colors in the surface.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [this article](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.textroad.com/pdf/JBASR/J.%2520Basic.%2520Appl.%2520Sci.%2520Res.,%25203(2s)120-124,%25202013.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwj8jr3yzYnNAhVLORoKHbs8A7oQFggoMAI&usg=AFQjCNG68cudae2CJjPHzSJeTX3Ax4OjBQ) about Hough transforms for square shaped objects detection

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to detect your object you can perform in two approaches:

1. As the background is white, you can do threshold based on colour. Also, try with different colour spaces.
2. Adjust the Threshold so that the background is black and foreground object is white. Here, your Threshold is inappropriate to the given image.

OR

1. Perform Bluer filtering on the image.
2. Followed by Edge(Canny or Sobel) detection
3. Then apply coutour and then you will see difference in your results.
4. After all this, if you still get bad result then proceed to Contour Area.